# Checking all the values in a matrix ocaml

Tags: matrix, ocaml

I have this matrix:

```
let arr = Array.make_matrix 4 4 0;;
```

and what to check if all elements are 0.
I heard of the function *for_all* but I can't quite figure it out how to use it with a matrix, since it expects an int array or a int list.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Array.html), here is everything you need to know:

```
val for_all : ('a -> bool) -> 'a array -> bool
```

`Array.for_all p [|a1; ...; an|]` checks if all elements of the array satisfy the predicate `p`. That is, it returns `(p a1) && (p a2) && ... && (p an)`.

Example: `Array.for_all ((=) 0)` has type `int array -> bool` and checks if all elements are zero.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is an array of arrays (or an array of rows if you prefer). So you need to execute a `for_all` on each one of the rows to check that all elements of the row are zero, and another outer `for_all` to check that all the `for_all`s over rows are true:

```
let arr = Array.make_matrix 4 4 0 in
Array.for_all (fun row ->
  Array.for_all ((=) 0) row) arr
```

Comment: As you've used partial application with `(=) 0` you could use it with `Array.for_all` to convert to `Array.for_all (Array.for_all ((=) 0)) arr`. Or if you dislike parens:  `arr |> Array.for_all @@ Array.for_all @@ (=) 0`